# How to open selection alert to choose installed native apps to open map by html or js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a location coordinate (lat, lng) and need a link to share it on social media like whatsapp, showing a map, but before doing it, it should open an alert to choose native installed application.

How to create a link that it can open a selection alert?

**Note**: **for instance, we wanna share this link on whatsapp. I know how to create shareable link for this app. All I need is about creating an alert to choose between native maps on mobile devices after opening the link.**

Comment: If you want to have several choices with your deeplink, you need to have several apps that may use this specific application.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` method to ask user for geolocation, but you need an https protocole to use this method, so locally it wouldn't work